# Class name changing dynamically from JSON object in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, json

I want to dynamically change a html class to an `<li>` element that I am getting over, but class name could not change. The code is here:

```
<div id="content">
    <ul id="container" ng-controller="ContainerController" ng-init="init()">
        <li ng-repeat="mainEvent in mainEvents" class="element home {{mainEvents.category}}" >
            <div ng-repeat="event in mainEvent.events">
            <a href="{{event.link}}" title="">
                <div class="images"><img ng-src="{{event.url}}"  alt=""/>

                    <div class="title">
                        <div class="title-wrap"><h3><span>{{event.title}}</span></h3></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="subtitle">
                        <div class="subtitle-wrap"><p><span><span class="line-through">{{event.short_text}}</span></span>
                        </p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also my JSON object like this:

```
"main_events": [

    {
        "category": "poland",
        "header": "Kasım 2014",
        "events": [

            {
                "title": "Beyaz Peynir",
                "url": "images/pic05.jpg",
                "short_text": "40.00 TL ",

                "tags": [
                    {
                        "name": "beacon"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "gps"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "navigasyon"
                    }
                ],
                "link": "blog-post-ic-mekan-konum-belirleme-sistemi.html"
            }

        ]
    },
```

I want to change my html class name dynamically according to category value. However, I always see class name like `class = "element home"`, but i want to see `class="element home poland"`. I know I may do this for a boolean or another method, but I don't understand that problem. It should be worked I supposed. So, How can solve this problem ? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Since you are repeating `mainEvent` use `{{mainEvent.category}}` insteaed of `{{mainEvents.category}}`**

Change `class="element home {{mainEvents.category}}"` to `class="element home {{mainEvent.category}}"`

Since `{{mainEvents.category}}` is an array, you cannot use this directly

```
<li ng-repeat="mainEvent in mainEvents" class="element home {{mainEvent.category}}" >
```

**Also you can use the ng-class syntax:**

There also you should take, `mainEvent.category`

```
 <li ng-repeat="mainEvent in mainEvents" class="element home"  ng-class="mainEvent.category" >
```

Comment: @Svravan i have tried this but i have seen again only class="element home " :(

Comment: Now, i tried again with ng-class syntax, i saw this when i inspect on chrome:
"<li ng-repeat="mainEvent in mainEvents" class="element home ng-scope" ng-class="mainEvent.category">" i don't understand

Comment: @AlperGuven make sure that `mainEvent.category` should not be `undefined`.

Comment: I think the variable you have taken is `main_events` not `mainEvents` please check that

Comment: @Alper Guven, have you checked the variable name?

Answer (score 0):

Change `class` to `ng-class`:

Snippet :

Change :

```
<li ng-repeat="mainEvent in mainEvents" class="element home {{mainEvents.category}}" >
```

This should also work, if you change `class="element home {{mainEvent.category}}"`

To:

```
<li ng-repeat="mainEvent in mainEvents" class="element home" ng-class="mainEvent.category">
```